# In-App Mail Account selection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

is it possible to have the user select an account from which he wants to send the mail ?

I can send a mail but it's always from the default account and i want the user to be able to select which account he will use to send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user taps on the From: address they can switch accounts, this behavior is identical to the normal email composer.

This is the code I'm using to launch the mail composer:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

AssetsLibraryBroker *libraryBroker = [[AssetsLibraryBroker alloc] init];
// loop through selected items;
for (NSString *fileName in [self.selectedDictionary allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"fileName: %@", fileName);
    [controller addAttachmentData:[libraryBroker getAssetDataForFileName:fileName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]  mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", fileName]];
}

[libraryBroker release];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

My mail composer has a tap-able "From:" field.

[image: Launched from Code] [image: select an account]

Comment: there is no such field on an MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: Yes there is, my app is using it and I have two accounts configured. What version of SDK are you using?

Comment: turns out you need multiple account configured to show the field, stupid of me. Thanks alot

I guess it's not possible to have the same picker in my app and have the user select in from there ?

Comment: You mean have the user select which account to send from before the picker is launched? No, it's not possible.

Comment: that's what i meant actually , but the From field satisfied the customer , so tyvm